# Exception in a Grails 2.3.8 app with facebook oauth2.0

Tags: grails, oauth-2.0, facebook-oauth, grails-2.3

I'm having the followings setup:

BuildConfig:

```
plugins {
  build ":tomcat:7.0.52.1"
  compile ":hibernate:3.6.10.13"
  compile ':spring-security-core:2.0-RC2'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth:2.0.2'
  compile ':spring-security-oauth-facebook:0.1'
}
```

Config:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.oauth.domainClass = 'com.mobilizr.OAuthID'

oauth{
  providers{
    facebook {
      api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
      key = '111111'
      secret = '333veeerysecret23234234234'
      successUri = '/oauth/facebook/success'
      failureUri = '/oauth/facebook/error'
      callback = "${baseURL}/oauth/facebook/callback"
    }
  }
}
```

When I click the link:

```
<oauth:connect provider="facebook" id="facebook-connect-link">Facebook</oauth:connect>
```

I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Must provide a valid url as callback. Facebook does not support OOB
```

I have no clue, what should that mean. The page [spring security oauth facebook](http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-oauth-facebook) doesn't give give too much details out. Does anyone have an idea, or maybe a working sample of FB-auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`baseURL` in the callback URL is your application server URL. Replace `baseURL` with your application server URL. e.g.,

```
callback = "http://localhost:8080/mySampleApp/oauth/facebook/callback"
```

and your error resolved.

One more thing replace `successUri` and `failureUri` as well. e.g.,

```
oauth {
  providers {
    facebook {
        api = org.scribe.builder.api.FacebookApi
        key = 'Your_Key'
        secret = 'Your_Secret'
        successUri = 'http://localhost:8080/mySampleApp/oauthCallback/success'
        failureUri = 'http://localhost:8080/mySampleApp/oauthCallback/error'
        callback = "http://localhost:8080/mySampleApp/oauth/facebook/callback"
    }
  }
}
```

and provide code to get data from Facebook. I have written code to get user info:

```
import grails.converters.JSON
import org.scribe.model.Token

class OauthCallbackController {

def oauthService

def index() {}

def success() {
    Token facebookAccessToken = (Token) session[oauthService.findSessionKeyForAccessToken('facebook')]
    if (facebookAccessToken) {
        def facebookResource = oauthService.getFacebookResource(facebookAccessToken, "https://graph.facebook.com/me")
        def facebookResponse = JSON.parse(facebookResource?.getBody())

        Map data = [id: facebookResponse.id, username: facebookResponse.username, name: facebookResponse.name, email: facebookResponse.email,
                first_name: facebookResponse.first_name, last_name: facebookResponse.last_name, birthday: facebookResponse.birthday,
                gender: facebookResponse.gender, link: facebookResponse.link, work: facebookResponse.work, hometown: facebookResponse.hometown,
                education: facebookResponse.education]

        render data
    } else {
        flash.error = "Token not found."
        render view: '/index'
    }
}

def error() {
    render params
}
}
```

---

[Working Code Repository](https://github.com/manishkbharti/FacebookOauth)

---

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Better to use `grails.serverURL` instead of localhost:8080 if app url per environment is different. :)

Comment: `oauthService.getFacebookResource()` is not available in the latest version anymore

Comment: I have create a sample app with your BuildConfig data. And it gives me the correct data from Facebook.

Comment: btw, the `key = 'Your_Key'` is it a `client token` or `app id`?

Comment: the dev removed this `oauthService.getFacebookResource()` from the oauthService and placed it into a separate plugin

Comment: I'm using the scaffolded controller, till now it seems to work... somehow

Comment: It's also helpful to set up a facebook test app and set the App Domains to 'localhost' and the Site URL to 'http://localhost:8080' :-)